# Why do american people use the word "Tube" instead of "TeleVision"?

Tags: meaning, american-english, word-usage

Do the following sentences make sense in modern English if I replace the word "Television" with "Tube"?

- Any ball games on the tube tonight?
- I was watching a horror movie on the tube.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cathode_ray_tube

Comment: You title does not match the question body.

Comment: Sigh!  I suppose there are those who have never seen an actual television tube.